# Ajax like loading when changing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This site: http://www.bienvillecapital.com/themes

Has somehow managed to make it look as if new content (when clicking on a link) is loaded with ajax. They also managed to remove the browser loading indicator.

Any ideas how this is done?

Comment: I see a browser loading indicator (the favicon flashes briefly)..?

Comment: Thats true, did not notice. but they removed the other loader

Comment: It's ajax, since the request you can see in Firebug are XHR request. `X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest` for `GET http://www.bienvillecapital.com/themes/japans-reflation`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Github Changing Pages and the URL so smoothly without AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216314/how-is-github-changing-pages-and-the-url-so-smoothly-without-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

This site is a [single-page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) you can add some similar functionality with JQuery create an event so every time the user clicks on a link the content will be loaded via ajax.

But single-page applications are more than just loading contents via AJAX. If you want to do it right you should use a modern JS framework like http://chaplinjs.org/ or http://angularjs.org/

There are many [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520532/reason-for-using-a-javascript-mv-framework/) to use one of those frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this **.ajaxComplete()** - http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

*example;*

```
$(document).(function(){

// Your Codes

}).ajaxComplete(function(){ 

alert("Ajax completed."); 

});
```

*it works each ajax process.*