# Backbone - Visitors Online Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I've googled but didn't found any answer or suggestion, how could I count the visitor in backbone. How could we know , when the user just browser our website at the first time. In asp.net MVC , I used to place it in `global.asx`, how about backbone.js?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that will call google analytics or that will call your own service to log user activity.

```
function OnUserAction(router, route, params){
  //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Once you have that function you can use the `route` event to execute it. From backbone's [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

> "route" (router, route, params) — Fired by history when any route has
>   been matched.

This allows you to bind an event to matched routes.

If you want to bind to all events, bind to "all":

```
myRouter.bind("all", OnUserAction);
```

So every time the user navigates the tracking code will be executed. To know if is the first time or not you is not that easy but google analytics "returning users" information will do the job for you.

**EDITED**

I'm going to add more details to try to explain how to implement it. I don't know what's your backbone level at the moment but you should know that backbone follows an architecture really similar to MVC and it is event-driven. It means that everything in the application is started by events and that the communication between modules is done through events as well.

In backbone you should never refresh the entire page or navigate to a new page, everything should be loaded and updated on demand via Ajax (I previously [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16520975/606821) more details about it). So when the URL changes it will trigger some event in the client. That event might have a handler that will call your ASP server but might as well don't call it.

In backbone there is a framework component that observes URL changes and trigger events when it happens. The component is called [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router). By default every time the URL changes the event `route` is triggered so you can bind an event handler like `OnUserAction` to that event.

You need to make sure that the handler (`OnUserAction`) of the event `route` will do something to log the user visits.

```
// Define our App and its components
App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Router: {} 
};

// Create the app router with a default action 
// called index for blank ('') route
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index'
  },

  index: function(){
    alert("Index route has been called..");
  }

});

//Route changes logic (route event handler)
function OnUserAction(router, route, params){
   // I don't know how are you planing to count the visits
   // one way would be to have in the server side an action 
   // that will store the user visits (like in the my example)
   // another way would be to post it to google analytics
   $.post(
     "/UserVisit/PlusOne", // This action will log visits in the database
     { url : route, args : params }, 
     function(data){
       console.log('/UserVisit/PlusOne executed with NO errors!');
     }
   );
}

// Tell the router that we want to execute OnUserAction on route event
App.Router.bind("route", OnUserAction);
```

if you find backbone hard to understand you might find useful [`chaplin.js`](http://chaplinjs.org/). Chapli.js wraps and simplifies backbone.js. As you earn expertise with it you will slowly learn about backbone (or at least that's the way I did).

Comment: To be honest with you, I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: I edited the answer to try to explain it to you in detail. Fell free to ask if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you want to use Backbone for this? It seems to be overkill if all you literally want to do is implement a visitor counter, you could use an AJAX call to simple server side script and achieve the same thing in much less code.